# Modifying Excel File in Function App Python

Tags: python, excel, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app

I have created a function HTTP trigger function in Azure Function using Python language. The script is working correctly as to how I want to modify the excel.

In the script, I have provided a local path for the excel files and I am saving the file locally. But what I would like to do is get this attachment from an email. To achieve this I am creating a logic app and triggering the Logic when a new email arrives.

Now I want to use the attachment in the function app. So how will I be able to read that attachment in Python script? Also, in the end, I want to return this excel so I can save this file using the File System.

[image: Azure Logic App]

Please see the function below to see how I am reading the file currently

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import openpyxl
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    wb = load_workbook(filename='test.XLSX')
    ws = wb.active
    wb.save('Test_Modified.xlsx')
return func.HttpResponse(f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file from the http request of the Azure Function you triggered from Logic App.

```py
import logging
import openpyxl
import azure.functions as func
import io

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    wb = load_workbook(filename = io.BytesIO(req.get_body()))
    # do stuffs
return func.HttpResponse(f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

If you need, you can return the bytes in the [http response of the Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python).

Comment: Thanks. How do I return this modified excel file in the function?

Comment: I am not much familiar to `openpyxl`. If you can get bytes from the workbook object, you can return the bytes in the [http response of the Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python) by passing that to the constructor of the http response object.